# Get the inputTextNumber using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

I'm trying to get the value of a `<p:inputTextNumber/>` using jQuery but any result is returning. I've tried this way. Can anyone help me?

```
<p:inputNumber class="valorCusto" id="valorCusto" value="#{produtoBean.produto.valorVenda}" symbolPosition="s" emptyValue="" minValue="0.00"  required="true" requiredMessage="O campo Valor Custo é obrigatório">
  <p:message for="valorCusto" />
</p:inputNumber>
```

```js
function calculaValorFinal(){      
  var c = $('.valorCusto').val();
  console.log(c);
}
```

Comment: do you want to get the real value or this `"#{produtoBean.produto.valorVenda}"` ? , btw can u share full your full xml?

Comment: I want get the #{produtoBean.produto.valorVenda}"

Comment: It's funny because when I change to <p:inputText> instead of <p:inputNumber> I get the result.

Answer (score 1):

Check first of all whether your dom element exists or not

If it exists then you should get its value either by

```
$('#valorCusto').val();
```

or

```
console.log($('#valorCusto').attr('value'));
```

make sure your form got prependId="false"

then access the value like this

```
alert(jQuery('#someID').val());
```

if you don't want to add prependId="false" to your form you will have to change the jquery selector from 
    jQuery('#someID').val()
 to

```
jQuery("[id$='someID']").val()
```

Comment: I've tried everything but it didn't work.  
It's funny because when I change to <p:inputText> instead of <p:inputNumber> I get the result

Comment: yes so is it necessary in your case to use <p:inputNumber>?
If yes then will update the answer as per that

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that jQuery's `.val()` is not linked to the value attribute because of "I have no idea why."

Try this:

```
console.log($('#valorCusto').attr('value'));
```

Comment: Now is undefined instead of blank.

Comment: Mmh then I'd need to see the resulting DOM element to give you a possible solution... You could try prop instead of attr, but I don't know. Search for your element in the resulting DOM by using a browser's devTools, check what's its ID, check if the value is stored in an attribute. I've never used PrimeFaces so I'm coming from an ignorant's position :)